# How to enable 16 bit applications on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, 16-bit

I need to enabled 16 bit applications from an installer on windows 8. I found that windows a supports 16 bit applications, and this support can be enabled by Control Panel->16 Bit Application Support. I would like to enable this automatically on a system. I was hopeful that some one might know if there was a registry key or api call or something that I could set so this would just work without having to manually configure it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: WTF, closed. I don't see this as off topic. It is a programming question and the answer was really helpful. Viewed 167 so far, so someone thought they should read it. Confused on why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is possible to do it autmoatically but if this option is disabled, Windows 8 will automatically asks you to enable the option whenever you try to run a 16-bit application. So that would not be a big deal.

Comment: Happens to be a big deal in my case, silent installer locks with an invisible popup. But it is looking like you are correct that there is no solution. Thanks ~Ben

Comment: Actually I have faced this problem in past and I searched it a lot but couldnt find a solution for that :)